# Confusion with JavaScript scoping

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a fair bit of understanding about JavaScript scoping -- that the language has function-level scope and the variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of their containing scope. However, I can't figure out why the following two pieces of code log different values:

This logs the value 1 to the console:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

And mysteriously, this  logs 10:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;        
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

So what's going on underneath the hood?

Comment: ['use strict'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/) would disallow declaring a function like in first example, so it's probably a Very Bad Idea to begin with.

Comment: Interesting but it's more like a design issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find the first example more mysterious...

In the second example, you do not declare a variable `a` inside of the function. So when you assign to `a`, it targets the `a` on the outside. Pretty straight-forward.

In the first example, you declare a variable `a` inside of the function, but in an unusual way: By declaring a function called `a`. So assigning to `a` will use that local "variable".

Two things to take away here:

a) Variable and function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of their scope. While `function a(){}` is written near the end, the variable `a` to hold it is already created and visible at the top of the scope.

b) Functions can be used as variables as well. You can pass functions around, you can re-assign function definitions. They share the same namespace with other variables.

Answer (score 2):

Its because when you use a declared `function` it is hoisted up and turned into a function expression, ie `var a = function() {};` This is creating a clash with your `a` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual-Studio for coding:

[image]

Programming the code in a TypeScript-File will enable you to see the variable Types by hovering the variable.

[image]

It will also warn you, when you try to apply the numerical-value 10 to the variable "a", that was first declared to be a function.
That's what I love about TypeScript, you can get more Information about it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Is there a warning message to go with the red line under the variable assignment?

Comment: inlined the image for you

Comment: Thanks, I added the warning Message @Thilo

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is interpreter based. Javascript `{block}` doesn't have a scope, but function have.

In your example,

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

first, you assign `a` to be integer 10, but in the end you reassign your `a` as a function that will be disappear at end of scope.

In this code,

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function foo() {}
}
b();
console.log(a);
```

your `a` not replaced, and returned to global scope, it'll log `10`.